# Cannot import custom module to a dag script in Airflow Docker

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have a dag in **puckel/docker-airflow** container and in dag script I imported a custom module from another script:

`from app_store_reviews.app_store_reviews.spiders.list_ids import ListIdsSpider`

Where:

`ListIdsSpider` is a class from *list_ids.py*. that's in this path = **'usr/local/airflow/dags/app_store_reviews/app_store_reviews/spiders'**

But I'm getting this kind of error from airflow:
`Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/reviews_analysis_dag.py] No module named 'app_store_reviews.app_store_reviews.spiders.list_ids'`

How I can solve this? Maybe add this path to *PYTHONPATH*? if so, How I can do this in a runing container?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you see an error in Airflow Web UI.
That error is thrown by airflow-scheduler when it scans your dag files.

You need to make sure your custom module is installed inside the airflow-scheduler environment.

Comment: how can I installed this module in airflow scheduler env?

Comment: It's really depends how you have airflow deployed. 
I assume you will have docker image. You need to pip install it into it.